# Angular - Conditional Formatting in for loop

Tags: html, angular

I have a for loop that print the content of an array. I would like one line to be highlighted.

The array is stored in my component.ts, as well as the line to highlight (but to simplify i'll fix it at 1)

I know this works:

```html
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="">

<div ng-style="{color: (1==1)?'aqua':'black'}">Sample Text</div>

</body>
```

And this print my array content in black properly

```
<div *ngFor="let i of this.getCode()">  {{i}} <br></div>
```

But when i try to have both it throws at runtime : `Cannot find a differ supporting object`

```
<div *ngFor="let i of this.getCode()" ngStyle="{color: (i==1) ? 'aqua' : 'black'}">  {{i}} <br></div>
```

[image]

Comment: I think this error is thrown, when your data, here `this.getCode()`, does not is an array. Please try to log it to the console and prove that it is an array.

Comment: if you are calling any method in your html then no need to write `this` you can direclty call `getCode()` and `getLineSelected()`

Comment: what code inside in getLineSelected ?

Comment: It's a simple getter from a variable. i replaced it with 1 with the same result.

Comment: Angularjs != Angular, which are you using and update the tag if needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First in your HTML, remove `this.` in HTML there is no need to write that.

For example:

**HTML**

```
<div *ngFor="let i of getCode()" [ngStyle]="{'color': i==getLineSelected() ? 'aqua' : 'black' }">
  {{i}}
  <br>
</div>
```

**TS**

```
 getCode() {
   return [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
 }

 getLineSelected() {
   return 1;
 }
```

You can play with [my code here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zwa9ts?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Comment: Thanks it works. So the missing `[ ]` around the `ngStyle` was the error. What is the meaning of these `[ ]` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, You can use `let i = index` to get the `index`

`<div *ngFor="let code of getCode(); let i = index" [ngStyle] ="{'color': (i==1) ? 'aqua' : 'black'}">  {{i}} <br></div>`